# Hot key to move email to specific folder in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am trying to look for a way that I can have a Hotkey that automatically moves a selected email to a folder.

Is there a way to do this with one press of a key? I know you can do ctrl+shift v but this still requires you to select the folder, which I do not want to do.

Comment: What's your Outlook version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a quick step, and configure the shortcut key.

[image]